# SQL Server Management Studio - Determine data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just created a table in SQL Server Management Studio and now I forget what datatypes I assigned to some of the fields. How do I access that information?

Comment: What exactly is SQL Studio Manager and which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you select a table name in the query window of Sql Server Management Studio
and press **ALT + F1** it will display the details of that table.

In the background shortcut key will execute sp_help on your behalf, so in this example it executes: sp_help users, which is much quicker than typing it.

[image]

[Source Here](http://www.developertipoftheday.com/2010/07/shortcut-key-for-table-details-in-sql.html)

Comment: Perfect. love it. For me the perfect solution without searching a table in object explorer

Comment: Thanks, for me I had to select the entire table names, not just the last one.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the table, choose 'Design table'.

Answer (score 2):

```
sp_help tablename . Gives you information about your table including fields and datatypes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = <yourtable>
```